# Pass payment method id to create charge

Tags: php, stripe-payments

**What is the issue about?**

I am trying to pass payment method id and customer to create single charge in php: https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/create

I have successfully retrieved the Payment Method id for Payment Methods For Single Charges

Here is the code i JQuery

```
cardButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    stripe.createPaymentMethod(
        "card", cardElement, {
            billing_details: { 
                name: cardHolderName.value
            }
        }
    ).then(function(result) {       
        //Payment Method id retrieved here...
    });

});
```

I have stripe customer ID, I also have stripe Payment Method id.

This is not about subscription...

As per the docs, there is no payment method property. How will I pass this info?

Comment: Payment method ID is on the Customer object... is that what you’re looking for?

Comment: Are you sending that Payment Method ID server-side so you can use it?  I'm not sure I understand what problem you're running into here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Charges API (https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/create) does **not** support passing a PaymentMethod object — it's an older API(https://stripe.com/docs/payments/legacy-apis)  and you would generally not use it in a new integration today.

Instead, you would use the PaymentMethod that you obtained with a PaymentIntent on the backend. For example:

https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment-synchronously

```
if data['payment_method_id']
  # Create the PaymentIntent
  intent = Stripe::PaymentIntent.create(
    payment_method: data['payment_method_id'], # from frontend
    amount: 1099,
    currency: 'usd',
    confirmation_method: 'manual',
    confirm: true,
  )
  # check intent.status for next steps...
```

Comment: Woo hooo! Thank you so much!